# Integrate by parts $x\cdot\arctan^2(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate by parts $\int x\cdot\arctan^2(x)~\mathrm{d}x$? I think this is easier to solve by substitution but I have to do this one by parts.

Thanks

P.S.: Any other helpful method or trick is obviously well accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HINT* $\displaystyle \int x\arctan^{2}(x)  = \frac{x^{2}}{2}\arctan^{2}(x) - 2\int \frac{x^2+1-1}{1+x^2}\arctan(x)$

Now integrate again.

Comment: In the final term of the integration by parts forming the new integral you seem to have forgotten that $ \int x dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+C $, so the 2's cancel out.